# Remove certian character from line by reading a file and save it to the file

Tags: python, pandas, file, readline

I have a problem. I have a corrupted csv file. The last column is a free text and my seperator is `;` unfortunately some users use `;` in the free text, e.g. `This is a longer text and;ups that should not be`. I want to read now the file line by line and after the second `;` everything should be replaced to a `,`. I print out which line of this csv file corrupted. How could read the file and replace it at the same time? Or should I save the lines + the output and replace it after?

Unfortunately I do not know how could I solve this kind of problem.

```py
import pandas as pd

with open("sample.csv", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
      x = line.split(";")
      if(len(x) > 3):
        print(i, ": ", line)
        cleaned_x = (', '.join(x[2:]))
        # Add cleaned_x to x
        new_line = x[0] + ";" + x[1]  + ";" + cleaned_x
        print(new_line)

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding="utf-8", sep=";")
```

What I have

```
customerId;name;text
1;Josey;I want to go at 05pm
2;Mike;Check this out --> öl
2;Frank;This is a longer text and;ups that should not be
2;Max;okay;
3;Josey;here is everythink good
```

What I want

```
customerId;name;text
1;Josey;I want to go at 05pm
2;Mike;Check this out --> öl
2;Frank;This is a longer text and,ups that should not be
2;Max;okay,
3;Josey;here is everythink good
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a custom func to read the csv file, then create a new dataframe from `rows` and `cols`:

```
def read_csv(path):
    with open(path) as file:
        for line in file:
            *v, t = line.strip().split(';', 2)
            yield [*v, t.replace(';', ',')]

cols, *rows = read_csv('sample.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
```

---

```
print(df)
  customerId   name                                              text
0          1  Josey                              I want to go at 05pm
1          2   Mike                            Check this out --> Ã¶l
2          2  Frank  This is a longer text and,ups that should not be
3          2    Max                                             okay,
4          3  Josey                           here is everythink good
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the lines in an array and create a new file.

```
import csv

new_sample = []
with open("sample.csv", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
for i, line in enumerate(file):
    x = line.split(";")
    if(len(x) > 3):
        print(i, ": ", line)
        cleaned_x = (', '.join(x[2:]))
        # Add cleaned_x to x
        new_line = x[0] + ";" + x[1]  + ";" + cleaned_x
        print(new_line)
        new_sample.append(new_line)
    else:
        new_sample.append(line)

with open("new_sample.csv", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as new_file:  # Open in write mode.
    writer = csv.writer(new_file)
    for row in new_sample:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'new_sample.csv'`

Comment: @Test, you need to change `new_sample.csv` to your file name

Comment: @Suman, you need to fix the indentation of your code, and add a `"r"` read flag to your first `open` block.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, if you use Python's csv library to write the initial file it will handle embeddded ; correctly

```
import csv

with open("test.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow(["hello", "world", "hello;world"])

# test.csv contains hello;world;"hello;world"
# which will be read as three fields using csv.reader
```

Here's how to fix your issue. I'll write out to a new file. It is possible to open a file in read/write mode but it's more complicated since you need to read a line, move the position in the file, write the new data while making sure you don't overwrite the bytes of the next line... It's much easier to use a new file then rename it.

```
import csv

with open("input.csv") as in_file, open("output.csv", "w") as out_file:

    reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=";")
    writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=";")

    for line in reader:  # line is a list containing the fields
        if len(line) > 3:
            line = line[:2] + [", ".join(line[2:])]
        writer.writerow(line)
```

If you don't need to save the fixed file you don't need to open "output.csv" or create the writer. Just print `line` after it's been corrected to display the list of fields `["hello", "world", "hello;world"]`

If you prefer to print the string that would end up in the file you will need to wrap fields containing semicolons in quotes.

```
line = [f"\"{item}\"" if ";" in item else item for item in line]
print(";".join(line))
# hello;world;"hello;world"
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas (version >= `1.3.0`) allows a function to be called to process a bad line when encountering one with the [on_bad_lines](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter:

> callable, function with signature (bad_line: list[str]) -> list[str] |
> None that will process a single bad line. bad_line is a list of
> strings split by the sep. If the function returns None, the bad line
> will be ignored. If the function returns a new list of strings with
> more elements than expected, a ParserWarning will be emitted while
> dropping extra elements. Only supported when engine="python"

So you could simply read the file with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep=';', engine='python', on_bad_lines=lambda x: x[:2] + [';'.join(x[2:])])
```

Then save it to whatever format you prefer. Or to achieve the output defined in the question:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(';', ',')
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=';')
```